# react js mapStateToProps triggers Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an index.js which renders all tables in the database.

```
_renderAllTables() {
const { fetching } = this.props;

let content = false;

if(!fetching) {
  content = (
    <div className="tables-wrapper">
      {::this._renderTables(this.props.allTables)}
    </div>
    );
}

return (
  <section>
    <header className="view-header">
      <h3>All Tables</h3>
    </header>
    {content}
  </section>
);
}

_renderTables(tables) {

return tables.map((table) => {
  return <Table
            key={table.id}
            dispatch={this.props.dispatch}
            {...table} />;               
});
}

render() {
return (
  <div className="view-container tables index">
    {::this._renderAllTables()}
  </div>
  );
 }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => (
  state.tables);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeIndexView);
```

I changed mapStateToProps from above code to below code.

```
 const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
tables: state.tables,
currentOrder: state.currentOrder,
});
```

The reason why I changed code is that I want to use one of state of currentOrder. I have a state which shows whether table is busy or not. So in order to use that I added currentOrder in mapStateToProps. However, it triggers Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined..

How can I use states from other components? any suggestions for that??

Thanks in advance..

--reducer.js

```
 const initialState = {
  allTables: [],
  showForm: false,
  fetching: true,
  formErrors: null,
   };


  export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
   switch(action.type){
    case Constants.TABLES_FETCHING:
        return {...state, fetching: true};

    case Constants.TABLES_RECEIVED:
        return {...state, allTables: action.allTables, fetching: false};

    case Constants.TABLES_SHOW_FORM:
        return {...state, showForm: action.show};

    case Constants.TALBES_RESET:
        return initialState;

    case Constants.ORDERS_CREATE_ERROR:
        return { ...state, formErrors: action.errors };


    default:
        return state;
   }
 }
```

Comment: The only call to `map()` here works on `this.props.allTables` and I don't see any place setting that to anything. Of course it will then be undefined. But I'm not sure what the actual question is since tht title says one, the question talks about "states from other components" etc. Could you clarify?

Comment: Oh, i thought it was not working because I tried to get states from other components... so I need to set this.props.allTables to something.. am I right?

Comment: Of course. It can't magically know what you're trying to do with a property you don't define

Comment: Thanks, so this.props.allTable is data that comes from database by httpGet... For this case how should i define it to render all tables properly??

Comment: Do you have reducer for this action? I think the problem is there

Comment: @D.R you sure `action.allTables` is returning correct array of table object?

Comment: @BasimHennawi Yes, I got 16 arrays which has their id and number..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that before fetching successfully `tables`, your component is rendered with `state.tables` is `undefined`.

First of all, best practice is to use selectors rather than json path like `state.tables`, to be in a separate `selectors.js` file using `reselect` lib as follow:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const tablesSelector = state => state.tables;

export default {
  tablesSelector,
}
```

Second, you need to add reducer for, let's assume, `FETCH_ALL_TABLES` action using `combineReducers` from `redux` lib and most important to initialize `tables` array with `[]` before the action is dispatched so as to be defined as follow:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

function tables(state = [], {type, payload}) {
  switch (type) {
    case 'FETCH_ALL_TABLES':
      return [
        ...state,
        ...payload,
      ]
  }

  return state;
}


export default combineReducers({
  tables,
});
```

and in your `index.js`, may be want update it to:

```
import selector from './selector';

...

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    tables: selector.tablesSelector(state),
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it okay when your initial state is an `array` but you return an `object`? it is `array` so you should return an `array` Why are you changing type?

Comment: @The Reason You're right. Just a typo, and fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for commenting, I have changed reducer and added selector.. but it still triggers same error... should I add separate reducer file?

Comment: my mapStateToProps looks like this now.  `const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  tables: selector.tablesSelector(state),
  currentOrder: state.currentOrder,
});`

Comment: Can you debug/use console.log to check these values:
`this.props` just in the first line in `_renderAllTables` method
`this.props.allTables` just before passing it to `_renderTables`
`payload` in your `reducer`

Comment: it shows undefined reference error... still undefined

Comment: console.log(this.props) in _renderAllTables returns objects (currentOrder, tables, dispatch, routes, history....) I dont get it why it is defined in this.props but it says that it is undefined...

Comment: Then you need to change `this.props.allTables` to `this.props.tables.allTables`

Comment: Thanks, I changed `this.props.allTables` to `this.props.tables.allTables` and it is working!

Comment: Anytime, dude! if you find the answer useful, vote it up. Good luck in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check if variable you want to map is defined.

```
_renderTables(tables) {
    if (tables) {
        return tables.map((table) => {
            return <Table
                key={table.id}
                dispatch={this.props.dispatch}
                {...table} />;               
        });
    }
}
```