# How to fix mapStateToProps from accessing an undefined state key without checking manually?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am creating a single page web application with React, with the state stored using Redux. When I access something like `state.workspace.guest.data` in `mapStateToProps()` it causes an exception crashing the application.

It appears `mapStateToProps()` is invoked before `componentDidMount()`, which invokes `this.props.getGuests()` action that actually causes `state.workspace.guest` to be initialized. The page loads properly when I manually enter the URL and press enter. However, `mapStateToProps()` causes an exception when I navigate through the application, with `state.workspace.guest` being `undefined`.

A possible solution would be to check if `state.workspace.guest` is defined. However, I feel there is a better way to do it? 
The answers in the following link suggest to use selectors. I am not sure if this is the solution to my problem, given I am new to Redux.

[react js mapStateToProps triggers Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586885/react-js-mapstatetoprops-triggers-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-map)

Here are the mapping functions.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        getGuests: Actions.getGuests
    }, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        guests : state.workspace.guest.data
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GuestSearchTable));
```

The `componentDidMount()` function which actually triggers an action which in turn loads the data.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getGuests();
    }
```

Here is the reducer.

```
const initialState = {
    data : []
};

function guestReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Actions.GET_GUESTS: {
            return {
                ...state,
                data : action.payload.data
            };
        }

        case Actions.GET_GUEST: {
            return {
                ...state,
                guest: action.payload.data
            };
        }

        case Actions.SAVE_GUEST: {
            return {
                ...state,
                guest: action.payload.data
            };
        }

        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
};
```

I expect the initial value of the `state.workspace.guest` to be `{ data : [] }`. But the actual value is `undefined`. The same problem appears in all the other pages.

Comment: Is your reducer connected to the store? It seems like you don't export your reducer to the store.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access data from guest key.

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        guests : state.workspace.guest.data
    }
}
```

I think you want to access state.workspace.data or you have to change key name to guests in reducer and the intialize state as follow:

```
return {
   guests: state.workspace.guests
}
```